# Inner Join + select the most recent

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have been trying to do the bellow query but honestly it's driving me crazy.

I have 2 Tables on MS SQL CE 4.0

Table 1 Name: Items

- ID
- Item_Code
- Logged_by
- Description

```
ID | Item_Code | Logged_by | Description

1  |    A      |   Pete    |    just an A
2  |    B      |   Mary    |    Seams like a B
3  |    C      |   Joe     |    Obviously this is a C
4  |    D      |   Pete    |    This is another A
```

Table 2 Name: Item_Comments

- ID
- Item_Code
- Comment
- Date

```
ID | Item_Code | Comment         |   Date

1  |    B      |    Done         |   2014/08/08
2  |    A      |    Nice A       |   2014/08/08
3  |    B      |    Send 1 More  |   2014/08/09
4  |    C      |    Done         |   2014/08/10
5  |    D      |    This is an A |   2014/08/10
6  |    D      |    Opps Sorry   |   2014/08/11
```

The wanted result: I'm looking to join the most recent comment from **Item_Comments** to the **Items** Table

```
ID | Item_Code | Logged_by | Description               | Comment

1  |     A    |     Pete   |    just an A              |  Nice A
2  |     B    |     Mary   |    Seams like a B         |  Send 1 More    
3  |     C    |     Joe    |    Obviously this is a C  |  Done           
4  |     D    |     Pete   |    This is another A      |  Opps Sorry
```

I did this query but I'm getting all the information =( mixed.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Items t1 
JOIN
     (SELECT Item_Code, Comment, MAX(date) as MyDate
      FROM Item_Comments
      Group By Item_Code, Comment, Date           
     ) t2
  ON Item_Code= Item_Code
ORDER BY t1.Item_Code;
```

Do you know any way to do this ?

Comment: Please tag the version of the database you are using.

Comment: Are you *sure* want the *older* items to change comments when a comment is "updated"?

Comment: Yes we need to see only the most recent, I'll create a button to see all the comments. thanks

Comment: @ElectricLlama I'm using SQL CE 4.0 (WebMatrix)

Comment: I've added that as a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select x.*, z.comment
  from items x
  join (select item_code, max(date) as latest_dt
          from item_comments
         group by item_code) y
    on x.item_code = y.item_code
  join item_comments z
    on y.item_code = z.item_code
   and y.latest_dt = z.date
```

**Fiddle test:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d387f/8/0

You were close with your query but in your inline view aliased as t2 you were grouping by comment, leaving the max function to not actually aggregate anything at all. In t2 you should have just selected item_code and max(date) and grouped only by item_code, then you can use that to join into item_comments (y and z in my query above).

This is a second way of doing this using a subquery, however I would stick to the above (a join w/ an inline view):

```
select i.*, c.comment
  from items i
  join item_comments c
    on i.item_code = c.item_code
 where c.date = (select max(x.date)
                   from item_comments x
                  where x.item_code = c.item_code)
 order by i.id
```

**Fiddle test:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d387f/11/0

Comment: OMG you are like a good or something, Thank You very much is working great, I'll study the query deeply.

Answer (score 0):

Note if you run this inside piece you get every single record:

```
  SELECT Item_Code, Comment, MAX(date) as MyDate
  FROM Item_Comments
  Group By Item_Code, Comment, Date
```

You want only the most recent comment. Assuming this is SQL Server 2008 or earlier, this get's you the most recent date for each Item_Code:

```
  SELECT Item_Code, MAX(date) as MyDate
  FROM Item_Comments
  Group By Item_Code
```

Now you need to join that back and look up the comment on that date:

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM Item_Comments C 
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT Item_Code, MAX(date) as MyDate
  FROM Item_Comments
  Group By Item_Code 
 ) t2
 ON  C.Item_Code= t2.Item_Code
 AND C.date = t2.MyDate
```

Now you can use that to join back to your original table:

```
SELECT t1.*, LatestComment.*
FROM Items t1 
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT C.* 
FROM Item_Comments C 
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT Item_Code, MAX(date) as MyDate
  FROM Item_Comments
  Group By Item_Code 
 ) t2
 ON  C.Item_Code= t2.Item_Code
 AND C.date = t2.MyDate
 ) LatestComment
 On LatestComment.Item_Code = t1.Item_Code
```

Depending on the actual database you are using, this can get much simpler. Thats why you need to tag your database and version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
create table items (id int, item_code char(1), logged_by varchar(10), description varchar(30));

insert into items values (1, 'A', 'Pete', 'just an A');
insert into items values (2, 'B', 'Mary', 'Seams like a B');
insert into items values (3, 'C', 'Joe', 'Obviously this is a C');
insert into items values (4, 'D', 'Pete', 'This is another A');


create table item_comments (id int, item_code char(1), comment varchar(20), date date);

insert into item_comments values (1, 'B', 'Done', '2014/08/08');
insert into item_comments values (2, 'A', 'Nice A', '2014/08/08');
insert into item_comments values (3, 'B', 'Send 1 More', '2014/08/09');
insert into item_comments values (4, 'C', 'Done', '2014/08/10');
insert into item_comments values (5, 'D', 'This is an A', '2014/08/10');
insert into item_comments values (6, 'D', 'Opps Sorry', '2014/08/11');

select * from items;
select * from item_comments;

select * from (select i.logged_by,i.id,i.item_code,i.description,ic.comment
,row_number() over(partition by i.id order by i.id )as Rnk
from items i inner join item_comments ic
on i.item_code=ic.item_code and i.id in(1,3)) x
where x.Rnk=1
union
select * from (select i.logged_by,i.id,i.item_code,i.description,ic.comment
,row_number() over(partition by i.id order by i.id )as Rnk
from items i inner join item_comments ic
on i.item_code=ic.item_code and i.id in(2,4)
) x where x.Rnk=2 order by item_code
```